# 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', InvalidURL("URL can't contain control characters. ' ' (found at least ' ')"))': /simple/pandas

Tags: python, pip

While trying to install any package using pip I am getting error:

for example pip install pandas --proxy proxy_value

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', InvalidURL("URL can't contain control characters. ' ' (found at least ' ')"))': /simple/pandas
```

I have uninstalled python and freshly installed python 3.9.13 and set the system variables to C:\Users\richa1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\

I have checked with 3.10.5 too.

But still not able to fix it. I am not sure if this is some issue with installed file or something I need to set.

Comment: What is `proxy_value`?

Comment: It is company specific value like http://proxy-xx.yyyy.com:nnn

Comment: Are you sure it's correctly formatted? The error implies it's not.

Comment: it is correctly formatted I believe since same command works on other machine

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Just found that proxy was set to http_proxy='', that is why error was showing found at least ''. Now I set it to empty http_proxy= and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. I wrote that out as an answer you can accept if you like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the error stems from a malformed HTTP proxy setting.

In this case, the `http_proxy` variable had been set to `''` instead of the empty string, and a quote character is indeed a control character not allowed in an URL.